# Native C++ dll in one solution with C# project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a source file written in C++, performing some simulation. I would like to create a user interface for this in C#. How can I have both C++ and C# in a single Visual Studio solution?

What I did so far was I created a .NET C# project and solution, and then a native project as a DLL library. I have marked the C# project as "Depends on" the C++ dll. I have provided the necessary `dllexport` directives and imported using `DllImport`. Everything compiles fine, but when I execute the application, the dll is not found:

> Unable to load DLL 'xxxx.dll': The specified module could not be found.

It is no surprise the DLL is not found, as the application is run from its output directory and the output directories are different for the C# and C++ projects. I do not want to write an explicit path as my import like `"..\..\Debug\xxxxx.dll".

Is there some common way how to structure a solution containing native a Dll and C# app so that the C# app can call the native Dll?

Comment: You could add a postbuild command to copy your C++ dll into the C# output folder, not sure this is best practice though

Comment: a brute force solution is to put it in c:\windows\system32\ or you have to put in the working directory.

Comment: @ppetrov this is what I'd recommend - you should post it as an actual answer

Comment: @DrewMcGowen It was quite short to make it an answer, but that is one way of solving the problem, so thanks for the advice, posted as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very comfortable way, which might have some unexpected drawbacks, but I do not see any so far: I can enable CLR for the C++ DLL project, making it "mixed", even if it in fact does not contain any managed code, and then the project building it can be made a Reference in the C# .NET project.

To make the project mixed mode set `Configuration Properties` / `General` / `Common Language Runtime Support` to `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`.

After this the build system copies the DLL into the application output folder automatically.

Comment: Exactly which setting did you enable to get the reference from your C# project to your native win32 C++ project to work?

Comment: @NoOneSpecial Added into the answer.

Comment: @Suma It doesn't work for me... After setting that, it gives `two-phase name lookup is not supported for C++/CLI or C++/CX; use /Zc:twoPhase-` warning, which is solved by setting `/Zc:twoPhase-` in `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line -> /Zc:twoPhase-` . Then no more warning while also built DLLs are not copied to C# project bin folder though

Answer (score 4):

If you know that after deployment your C++ DLL will be in the same folder as your C# DLL (or executable), then on simple way to solve the problem is to use the PostBuild event (Project properties, Build events).

You can add a copy command that will put your C++ DLL into the C# output folder.